# Powershell script using get-process and get-content

Tags: powershell

Trying to create Powershell script to find process that is not running on a list of computers (text file).  I have found below script but I am not sure how to utilize the get-content cmdlet with it.

```
$ProcessName = "VPDICOMServer"
if((get-process $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null)
echo "Process is not running" }else{ echo "Process is running" }
```

Comment: So what did you try? What *can* you do so far? Can you loop through all the computers in your file printing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `computers.txt` file is new-line separated list of computer names, you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
$ProcessName = 'VPDICOMServer'
$Path = "$Env:UserProfile\Documents\computers.txt"

foreach ($Computer in (Get-Content -Path $Path)) {
```

and then you can execute `Get-Process` against each one (assuming you have privileges):

```
    if (Get-Process -ComputerName $Computer -Name $ProcessName -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue') {
        'Process is running'
    } else {
        'Process is not running'
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!  That worked!   Just wondering however if I can get the response to also show computer name.  Right now I just get a list with "process is running" or "process is not running" and I have to match up with list of computers names.

Comment: @Amiehl Sure- `"${Computer}: Process is running"` note the double-quotes.

Comment: @Amiehl Normally you can achieve this variable replacement without the special syntax (`${}`), but because `:` can be used to define drive/scope, it's necessary in this example.  As an example to what I mean, this is also valid: `"$Computer - Process is running"`

Comment: Thanks.  That is so helpful.  I knew I had to put that $Computer somewhere - I just was trying to put it in the wrong place.